# Torch write text to file

Tags: lua, lua-table, torch

I'm trying to write text to file according to this documentation:
https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/serialization.md

With the following code:

```
require 'torch'
torch.save('temp.txt','text')
```

A new file named **temp.txt** is created but when I open it in text editor I see a few null symbols before the text.

Is there an other way to do it?

Comment: write output this command: xxd FILENAME

Answer (score 3):

`torch.save` does not write only text to the file, but it serializes the given object, so these bytes are probably type of object and length of the string or similar. This is the intended way.

If you want to write a file with text only, use normal Lua API:

```
fd = io.open('temp.txt', 'w')
fd:write('text')
fd:close()
```